# Error getting JSON using Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm working on an academic project. There's a JAVA backend that creates a JSON response for me in another server. The JSON is perfect and I can see it from a browser at any other node.

My job is to parse this JSON and display in HTML.

Here's a piece of code I'm using:

```
    function sendQueryToBackend () {
    var strURL = "http://10.2.4.234:8080/RestSimpleApp/rest/BingSearch?q=india&callback"; // this is not my system
    alert("Searching...MAIN");
    $.ajax({
        url:strURL,
        async:false,
        type:"GET",
        success: function(result)
           {
                alert("It works!" ); // This alert never comes up
           }
    });
}
```

In the function, I just want to see whether it receives the data or not.
This alert never comes up.

However if I'm using a local file with the same JSON format, it works perfectly and I can parse it to display as I wish. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try adding `error: function(error) { }` and inspecting the error object.

Comment: Are you making a *cross-domain* request? Because then you'd better use JSONP

Comment: what it shows if you inspect this request in firebug? can you try this in Firefox and add your observation?

Comment: i test it and i found there is some problem in strURL .

Comment: why `async: false`, it is a very bad chouce

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a Cross Origin Resource Sharing issue to me.

If the resource uses cookies, you'll need to add this to the ajax call:

```
'xhrFields': {'withCredentials': true},
```

You should also check that the resource has the appropriate `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header and it might also need `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type`. Since it's not your script, this is something the project maker should fix if necessary.

Finally, if there's a redirect involved (i.e. typing that URL in your address bar redirects to another before showing content, even if just changing the case), you'll need to change the URL to be the *final* URL.